# Limits infinite with fraction

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)^{10}+(x+2)^{10}+\cdots+(x+100)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}$$
Seems easy but no idea how to do it

Thanks

Comment: People will be more inclined to help you if you say what you've tried already and what specifically is giving you trouble.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to type questions like this using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, it is important to show effort, post work and describe where you are having issues. Regards

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x^{10}$. Note that for example $\frac{(x+2)^{10}}{x^{10}}=\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{10}$.

Comment: Sorry for the non effort and thanks for the answer Andre Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

Using sumation we can write
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{100}(x+n)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{100}x^{10}(1+n/x)^{10}}{x^{10}+10^{10}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{100}(1+n/x)^{10}}{1+(10/x)^{10}}=\sum_{n=1}^{100}1=100$$

Comment: my answer is corrected

Answer (score 1):

You need only consider the ratio of the leading terms in the numerator and denominator since they will dominate. There are 100 copies of $x^{10}$ in the numerator, so you need only compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{100x^{10}}{x^{10}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} 100 = 100$.